# Feature selection with XGBoost

Tags: feature-selection, hyperparameter, boosting

XGBoost will produce different values for feature importances with different hyperparameters on the same dataset. When using XGBoost as a feature selection algorithm for a different model, should I therefore optimize the hyperparameters first? Or there are no hard and fast rules, and in practice I should try say both the default and the optimized set of hyperparameters and see what really works?

Comment: You shouldnt use xgboost as a feature selection algorithm for a different model. Different models use different features in different ways. Theres no reason to believe features improtant for one will work in the same way for another.

Comment: @MatthewDrury I'll write this up as an answer, but if you'd prefer to make this comment into an answer, I'll delete my quotation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From comments, Matthew Drury writes:

> You shouldn't use xgboost as a feature selection algorithm for a different model. Different models use different features in different ways. Theres no reason to believe features important for one will work in the same way for another.